# Finding a chessboard in an image

Tags: algorithm, opencv

So, I initially assumed that finding a chessboard in an image should be trivial because it is such an easily defined object. However it isnt so easy and I was wondering if someone knows how the chessboard finder "cvFindChessboardCorners" works in OpenCV. Ive tried googling it but havnt managed to find the algorithm. Im guessing maybe the following:

1)Binarize
2)Open and close to eliminate small clusters

A)
2)Find Harris corners
3)Create distance matrix between all points in image
4)...?

B)
2)Find hough transform
3)all significant lines are checked for where they intersect. If 4 or more lines intersect at a point then these lines are part of the chessboard. This includes the point at infinity.
4)?

Anyone know exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty ... complicated :) If you want to know exactly, the source of opencv would be the place to look - in opencv 2.2 it's in `modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp` line 219. It also has a `DEBUG_CHESSBOARD` compile switch to be able to see how it works.